# Using variables in typescript, angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm sure this is a stupid question, but I'm new to this language and for sure I'm missing something.
I just want to exectute this code:

.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Provider } from '../shared/provider.module.ts';
import { Testcase } from '../shared/testcase.module.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-test',
  templateUrl: './single-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-test.component.scss']
})
export class SingleTestComponent implements OnInit {

  a: int = 2;
  b: int = 3;
  c: int = a*b; 
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

.html

```
<div>{{c}}</div>
```

but on the console I get this error:

````
``` ERROR ReferenceError: a is not defined   
    at new SingleTestComponent (main.js:89)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.SingleTestComponent_Factory [as factory] (main.js:105)
    at getNodeInjectable (vendor.js:14920)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (vendor.js:18838)
    at createDirectivesInstances (vendor.js:18212)
    at ɵɵelementStart (vendor.js:25536)
    at Module.ɵɵelement (vendor.js:25587)
    at AppComponent_Template (main.js:181)
    at executeTemplate (vendor.js:18185)
    at renderView (vendor.js:17994)```

what am I missing?
````

Comment: `this.a` and `this.b` as they're attributes of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "this.propertyName". See the example:

```
export class SingleTestComponent implements OnInit {
  a: number = 2
  b: number = 3
  c: number = this.a * this.b

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Provider } from '../shared/provider.module.ts';
import { Testcase } from '../shared/testcase.module.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-test',
  templateUrl: './single-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-test.component.scss']
})
export class SingleTestComponent implements OnInit {

  a = 2;
  b = 3;
  c = this.a * this.b;  
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```